# Did the Duke of Cambridge wear rouge?

Tags: military, 19th-century, cultural-history, royalty

I'm looking for evidence that the [Prince George, Duke of Cambridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_George,_Duke_of_Cambridge) - Queen Victoria's cousin and the Commander-in-Chief of the British Army - enhanced his complexion by the judicious and semi-discreet use of the rouge pot.

Several men of standing in the nineteenth century were known for their attempts to hold back the hands of time, either through corsetry, hair dye or cosmetics (or a combination of the three). Most of them were elderly roués and/or remnants from the Regency period. Lord Ranelagh was one; Lords Palmerston, Lyndhurst and Malmesbury were three more (from [*The life of Benjamin Disraeli, earl of Beaconsfield, Volume 6*](https://books.google.com/books?id=1t7Jr8apQt8C&pg=PP23&dq=life%20of%20disraeli%20rouge&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjcn6iPkufuAhXZJTQIHcQ9AWkQ6AEwAXoECAYQAg#v=onepage&q=rouged&f=false)):

[image]

I know (or at least I think I know) that I read a long time ago that the Duke of Cambridge was another but I can't for the life of me remember now where I read it.

At least three Wilkie Collins novels include such a figure. WC pretty much had a finger on the pulse of contemporary culture so it's safe to assume that this was a recognised phenomenon of his day.